# Rails ActiveAdmin - change the after update redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Feature page that belongs to the Car page. That is working exactly how I want to, except for one thing.

After creating, updating or destroying, I want the page to be redirected to the `admin_car_path(car)` instead of the defaults `admin_car_feature_path(car,feature)` for create and update and `admin_car_features_path(car)`.

I unsuccessfully searched for that.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Car do
end

ActiveAdmin.register Feature do
  belongs_to :car
end
```

TIA

Comment: I wish there was a single well written up to date generic answer instead of 7 okayish somewhat duplicated ones.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is the code for update action for your case. This code goes to the features.rb - admin file:

```
controller do
  def update
    update! do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_cars_path }
    end
  end
end
```

This redirects to the cars index page. So you have the idea. Same for create and destroy actions.

Comment: another good thing about this approach: it does not override validation errors being shown on edit page when the object is invalid (as I feared it might since the block doesn't distinguish whether valid or not).

Comment: Instead of `format.html { redirect_to admin_cars_path }` you could use the generic approach `format.html { redirect_to collection_path }`

Comment: Thank you guys. Im sorry for the late confirmation.

Comment: this method actually ignores validation errors (maybe in latest active_admin versions), I have posted code that works for me

Comment: I am getting this error:
development/myproject/app/admin/features.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `controller' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 49):

right code for updating without skipping validation

```
controller do
  def update
    super do |success,failure|
      success.html { redirect_to collection_path }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
development/myproject/app/admin/features.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `controller' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it should be placed inside ActiveAdmin.register ModelName do end block

Comment: It's not recommended to use the `super` keywords in AA (silly, I know. DSL overkill IMO). that's essentially what the `update!` method is for. You can also do `update! do |success, failure|`

Answer (score 13):

At the current moment accepted answer leads to ignoring validation errors.

This works for me with the latest versions of ActiveAdmin and Rails:

```
controller do

  def update
    update! do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to collection_path } if resource.valid?
    end
  end

  def create
    create! do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to collection_path } if resource.valid?
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
development/myproject/app/admin/features.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `controller' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, the post is from 2014, I haven't used ruby for 2 years now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that also works with `create_another`, using `parent` and `child` for model names.

This solution assumes that you show children as part of parent (e.g. via `table_for`) so you do not need child's `index` method.

In resource override controller's `smart_resource_url` and `index` methods:

```
  controller do
    def smart_resource_url
      if create_another?
        new_resource_url(create_another: params[:create_another])
      else
        parent_path(params[:parent_id])
      end
    end

    def index
      redirect_to parent_path(params[:parent_id])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Current answer is skipping validations. Some of the other answers are working but partially correct (incorrect use of `super` or manually validating resource).

Most updated "proper" way to redirect with AA after create and udpate:

```
controller do
  def create
    create! do |success,failure|
      success.html { redirect_to collection_path, notice: "#{resource.model_name.human} was successfully created." }
    end
  end
  def update
    update! do |success,failure|
      success.html { redirect_to collection_path, notice: "#{resource.model_name.human} was successfully updated." }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcelo, I'm not sure I understand your question, but wouldn't putting this into the `update`, `create` and `destroy` actions in your controller do the trick?

```
 format.html { redirect_to redirect_address }
```

And make `redirect_address` whatever you need.