# How do I change redirect page in bang version update in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I don't know the syntax of it.

```
update! do {
     success: admin_user_path
   }
```

Is this the right syntax?
Im using Active Admin

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you may want http://stackoverflow.com/a/11598123/1008891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the details on handing success/failures on the [Inherited Resources readme](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#overwriting-actions). ActiveAdmin uses Inherited Resources for all of its controller actions.

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def update
    update! do |success, failure|
      success.html { redirect_to project_url(@project) }
      failure.html { redirect_to root_url }
    end
  end
end
```