# After create, redirect to edit_path instead of show path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Problem is simple (solution is not): I would like to redirect to edit path after X model is created (I'll apply this to multiple models).

Are there any way to do it? I'm digging in source code, trying to find a reference to created instance, but can only find instance variables named after model (like `@user`, which is harder to make generic).

So far, I found this answer which **partially** solves my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486025/312907

I'm still missing a reference to created model object.

Comment: In the answer below your linked answer, `resource` is the created model object.

Comment: Oh man, thanks you @zwippie , I've lost so much time on this! Why don't you post it as an answer? I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActiveAdmin, just modify smart_resource_url, so that you don't have to mess with the create or update code:

```
controller do 
  def smart_resource_url
    if create_another?
      new_resource_url(create_another: params[:create_another])
    else
      edit_resource_url
    end
  end
end
```

If you want it to go back to the list view, put "collection_url" after the else.

If you want it to go back to the edit page, put "edit_resource_url" after the else.

Note that this redirect occurs BOTH after creating a new resource and after editing one.

Comment: Than you, this is very helpful. I can differentiate between the "source action, to apply this only to new and call super in the other case

Answer (score 2):

The created model object is accessible in the controller method as variable `resource`.

Comment: Thanks! Need to wait 4 minutes before I can accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to edit action after creating the object from with in the controller itself
for example

```
  def create
    @x = X.new(x_params)
    if @x.save
      redirect_to edit_x_path(@x)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sorry, this is related specifically to activeadmin, not to rails only, so I wanted to use the resource generated by activeadmin, I don't have control over how's generated.